# How to make a table with minimum width, without data going onto a new line?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with data in it. However, the strings in each cell is varies in length. I know the data will never be longer than 50 characters. How can I make the smallest possible width table. I've tried setting the with in percentages but that only makes it to the percentage of the screen. If I put a pixel width then the string overflows into a new line.

```
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

td, th {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Jason</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>Australia</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: do you want to set maximum and minimum  `width` to 50 characters

Comment: @לבנימלכה I just wrote 50 characters so people know the string isn't so that it overflows onto a new line because its so long. I just want to ensure the width of the table automatically adjusts so the width is as small as possible

Comment: and if one of the `td` longer then the smallest to hide part of text?

Comment: @לבנימלכה so whatever the longest string in a column is, thats wit width of that column (this the table remains at minimum width. Nothing gets hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsbin.com/hodusadike/edit?html,output

Try the above example. Keeping `table-layout: auto !important;` for the Table and `width: auto !important;` will give you the result you need. I haven't tried it with Firefox or IE (works well on Chrome and Safari ).

I recommend using it with either `.class` or `#id` as the above code will change every table in your site with this specifications.

Cheers.

Comment: The link you shared has nothing to do with tables.

Comment: hi Paul, I have shared with you code to your problem. Can you check on the right panel of the jsbin page?

Comment: The jsbin is a very weird. It doesn't show anything. I have to click the little arrow on the right hand corner, then inspect element. Is there a way to do something like auto + 10 px. So It finds the minimum width and adds 10px more to the width?

Answer (score 0):

For simple solution, use `max-width` option with `ch` unit. And `white-space: nowrap` -like this:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%
}

td, th {
  max-width: 50ch; /* 50 characters */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Jason</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>example - lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr , sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</td>
    <td>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr , sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```